# Drawing a vertical line on ImagveView in android on touch

Tags: android, imageview, drawing, line

I have been trying to get my head around this problem since weeks but I haven't found any solution. 
I am trying to create an imageview and when a user touches the view, a dashed line must appear and as the user drags his finger around, the line must move horizontally. Height of the line is the complete imageview's height.

I saw many tutorials on the internet for this, tried many solutions but none worked. This may be due to the fact that I am new to android development.

Please Help

Comment: make a custom `ImageView` and override its `onTouchEvent` and  `onDraw` methods

Answer (score 1):

Finally this solved the problem. Had to call invalidate() within onTouchEvent().

Here is the code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(touchX,0,touchX,canvas.getHeight(),paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        touchX = event.getX();

        touchY = event.getY();

/*
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(touchX,touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(touchX,touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
*/
        invalidate();
        return  true;
        }
```